# Objetos y clases: ¿Cómo agrego productos a una clase desde un objeto?

Tags: javascript

la cosa es así. Tengo un restaurante y quiero tener automatizado las cuentas de cada mesa. Por eso tengo:
 1. Un objeto **"producto"**. Este contiene una lista con todos los productos que se venden ("café", "té", etc.) y tiene funciones para agregar, eliminar o modificar.
 2. Una clase con **"productoConsumido**. Esta clase son los productos que consumen las mesas/clientes.
 3. Una clase con **"mesa"**. Estas son todas mis mesas.
 4. Un objeto **"mesasActivas**. Puedo eliminar mesas, agregarlas, cerrar cuenta. Tambien, agregar productos (se convierten en productoConsumido), eliminarlos.

Mi problema es que la última parte no me sale. No puedo agregar productos por ende tampoco eliminarlos ni cerrar la cuenta. Paso el código de todo para que se puedan graficar bien. Muchas gracias.

```
const producto = {
    lista: [],
    agregar: function (id, nombre, precio) {
        this.lista.push({
            id,
            nombre,
            precio
        })
    },
    modificar: function (id, dataProducto) {
        for (let producto of this.lista) {
            if (producto.id == id) {
                let misKeys = Object.keys(dataProducto);
                for (let key of misKeys) {
                    producto[key] = dataProducto[key];
                }
            }
        }
    },
    eliminar: function (id) {
        const index = this.lista.findIndex(producto => {
            return producto.id == id;
        });
        if (index == -1) {
            throw "Error: El id buscado no existe";
        }
        this.lista.splice(index, 1);
    }
};


class ProductoConsumido {
    constructor(producto, cantidad) {
        this.producto = producto;
        for(let item of mesasActivas.lista){
            if (producto == item) {
                this.product=item;
            }
        }
        this.cantidad = parseInt(cantidad);
    }
}


class Mesa {
    constructor(id) {
        this.lista = [];
        this.id = id;
    }
}



const mesasActivas = {
    lista: [],
    ID: function (mesa) {
        mesa.id=parseInt(mesa.id);
        if (isNaN(mesa.id)) {
            throw "El ID de la mesa debe ser un número.";
        }
    },
    chequearID: function (mesa) {
        this.ID(mesa);
        let index = this.lista.findIndex((mesaactiva) => {
            return mesaactiva.id === mesa.id});
        if (index > -1) {
            throw "mesa ocupada";
        }
    },
    agregarMesa: function (mesa) {
        let mesaNueva = new Mesa(mesa);
        this.ID(mesaNueva);
        this.chequearID(mesaNueva);
        this.lista.push(mesaNueva);
    },
    eliminarMesa: function (mesa) {
        let index = this.lista.findIndex((mesaactiva) => {
            return mesaactiva.id === mesa.id});
        this.lista.splice(index,1);
    },
    agregarProductos: function (nombre, cantidad) {     
          //Busco si existe el producto en mesa
          for(let productoConsumido of this.lista) {
            if(productoConsumido.producto == nombre) {
                productoConsumido.cantidad += cantidad;
                return true;
            }
        }
        //Busco en productos mi producto para agregarlo
        let productoEncontrado = producto.lista.find(producto => {
            return producto.nombre == nombre;
        });
        if(typeof productoEncontrado == "undefined") {
            throw "Producto inexistente.";
        }
        const productoConsumido = new ProductoConsumido(productoEncontrado, cantidad);
        this.lista.push(productoConsumido);
    }, 
    cerrarCuenta: function () {
        let cuenta = this.lista.reduce ((acumulador, productoConsumido) => {
            let cuentaFinal = productoConsumido.producto.precio;
            return acumulador += productoConsumido.cantidad * (cuentaFinal);
        }, 0)
        return cuenta;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

se hicieron algunas correcciones y se pusieron console.log para hacer una interacción mas fácil. agregue jquery para poder manejar los eventos algo mas sencillo y rápido ya que el html que hice es meramente un ejemplo de como podría ser que funcione la lógica de la aplicación.

algunas de las funciones hechas estaban funcionando correctamente, pero también había algunos errores de lógica en las funciones agregarProductos y cerrarCuenta

el detalle mas a destacar es que estabas usando `this.lista` sobre el objeto `mesasActivas` y entiendo que lo que intentabas hacer era sacar los productos de una mesa pero `mesasActivas.lista` tiene una lista de mesas, la forma correcta era `mesasActivas.list[indexMesa].lista` y asi sacabas los productos de una mesa

```js
$("#agregar-mesa").click(function(e){
  let mesa = $("#agregar-mesa-value").val()
  mesasActivas.agregarMesa(mesa)
  
  //console.log(mesasActivas.lista)
})

$("#eliminar-mesa").click(function(e){
  let mesa = $("#eliminar-mesa-value").val()
  mesasActivas.eliminarMesa(mesa)
  
  //console.log(mesasActivas.lista)
})

$("#agregar-producto").click(function(e){
  let mesa = $("#agregar-producto-mesa").val()
  let producto = $("#agregar-producto-producto").val()
  let cantidad = $("#agregar-producto-cantidad").val()
  mesasActivas.agregarProductos(mesa, producto, cantidad)
  
  //console.log(mesasActivas.lista)
})

$("#cerrar-cuenta").click(function(e){
  let mesa = $("#cerrar-cuenta-mesa").val()
  let cuenta = mesasActivas.cerrarCuenta(mesa)
  if(cuenta !== undefined){
    console.log('total a pagar $' + cuenta)
  }
})

const producto = {
    lista: [
      { id:1, nombre : 'producto 1', precio : 1.5 },
      { id:2, nombre : 'producto 2', precio : 3.5 },
      { id:3, nombre : 'producto 3', precio : 5.5 }
    ],
    agregar: function (id, nombre, precio) {
        this.lista.push({
            id,
            nombre,
            precio
        })
    },
    modificar: function (id, dataProducto) {
        for (let producto of this.lista) {
            if (producto.id == id) {
                let misKeys = Object.keys(dataProducto);
                for (let key of misKeys) {
                    producto[key] = dataProducto[key];
                }
            }
        }
    },
    eliminar: function (id) {
        const index = this.lista.findIndex(producto => {
            return producto.id == id;
        });
        if (index == -1) {
            throw "Error: El id buscado no existe";
        }
        this.lista.splice(index, 1);
    }
};


class ProductoConsumido {
    constructor(producto, cantidad) {
        this.id = producto.id
        this.producto = producto.nombre;
        this.precio = producto.precio
        this.cantidad = parseInt(cantidad);
        
    }
}


class Mesa {
    constructor(id) {
        this.lista = [];
        this.id = id;
    }
}

const mesasActivas = {
    lista: [],
    ID: function (mesa) {
        mesa.id = parseInt(mesa.id);
        if (typeof mesa.id !== 'number') {
            throw "El ID de la mesa debe ser un número. pero es " + typeof mesa.id;
        }
    },
    chequearID: function (mesa) {
        this.ID(mesa);
        let index = this.lista.findIndex((mesaactiva) => {
            return mesaactiva.id === mesa.id
        });
        if (index > -1) {
            throw "mesa ocupada";
        }
    },
    agregarMesa: function (mesa) {
        try {
          let mesaNueva = new Mesa(mesa);
          this.ID(mesaNueva);
          this.chequearID(mesaNueva);
          this.lista.push(mesaNueva);
          console.log('mesa agregada')
        }catch(e){
          console.error(e)
        }
    },
    eliminarMesa: function (mesa) {
        let index = this.lista.findIndex((mesaactiva) => {
            return mesaactiva.id === mesa.id
        });
        
        if(index > -1){
          this.lista.splice(index,1);
          console.log('mesa eliminada')
        }
        else
          console.error('mesa no existe')
    },
    agregarProductos: function (mesa, nombre, cantidad) {
        try {
          // busca la mesa
          let indexMesa = this.lista.findIndex((mesaactiva) => {
            return mesaactiva.id == mesa
          });
          if(indexMesa == -1) throw 'Mesa no se encontro'
        
          //Busco si existe el producto en mesa
          for(let productoConsumido of this.lista[indexMesa].lista) {
              if(productoConsumido.producto == nombre) {
                  productoConsumido.cantidad += cantidad;
                  console.log('producto sumado a la cantidad')
                  return true;
              }
          }
          
          //Busco en productos mi producto para agregarlo
          let productoEncontrado = producto.lista.find(producto => {
              return producto.nombre == nombre;
          });
          
          if(typeof productoEncontrado == "undefined") {
              throw "Producto inexistente.";
          }
          
          const productoConsumido = new ProductoConsumido(productoEncontrado, cantidad);
          this.lista[indexMesa].lista.push(productoConsumido);
          console.log('producto agregado')
        }catch(e){
          console.error(e)
        }
    }, 
    cerrarCuenta: function (mesa) {
        try {
          let indexMesa = this.lista.findIndex((mesaactiva) => {
            return mesaactiva.id == mesa
          });
          if(indexMesa == -1) throw 'Mesa no se encontro'
          
          let cuenta = this.lista[indexMesa].lista.reduce ((acumulador, productoConsumido) => {
              let cuentaFinal = productoConsumido.precio;
              return acumulador += productoConsumido.cantidad * (cuentaFinal);
          }, 0)
          
          this.lista.splice(indexMesa, 1)
          
          console.log('cuenta cerrada y mesa desocupada')
          
          return cuenta;
        }catch(e){
          console.error(e)
        }
    }
}
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.title {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span class="title">Agregar mesa</span>
  <input id="agregar-mesa-value" type="number" placeholder="numero mesa"/>
  <button id="agregar-mesa">agregar</button>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="title">Eliminar mesa</span>
  <input id="eliminar-mesa-value" type="number" placeholder="numero mesa"/>
  <button id="eliminar-mesa">eliminar</button>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="title">agregar producto a mesa</span>
  <input id="agregar-producto-mesa" type="number" placeholder="numero mesa"/>
  <input id="agregar-producto-producto" type="text" placeholder="producto nombre"/>
  <input id="agregar-producto-cantidad" type="number" placeholder="cantidad"/>
  <button id="agregar-producto">agregar</button>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="title">cerrar la cuenta</span>
  <input id="cerrar-cuenta-mesa" type="number" placeholder="numero mesa"/>
  <button id="cerrar-cuenta">cerrar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: prueba lo en pagina completa, o no se alcanzaría a ver el contenido completo